# What does "no ports" on netstat -s mean?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, tcp, netstat, stats

On Windows server 2016, when I execute, in a cmd prompt, "netstat -s" I get a bunch of statistics.  One of those is "No Ports".

[image]

What does this mean?  Is this the number of times no port was found to be available when requested?  Or does this refer to the number of ports currently in use?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refer to the number of times a connection was made to a port but failed, so yes it is the number of times no port was available.

the reason why it was not available could be because it is not open or simply already in use by another process because of conflict for example

Comment: And is the value cumulative since the last reboot?

Comment: @Vincent yes it the total number since the last reboot